# How i can display the data found in the list without executing the else statement while fetching sqlite data flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

I am fetching data from SQLite database, where I want to display that data for which the index is matched to specific data in the complete database, I can display that data**
But

The issue is for non-matched data the else statement executes which I
don't want.

---

this is my Code:

```dart
            SizedBox(
              height: 490.h,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: loadData(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: listData.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          int nIndex = listData[index]['Surah'];
                          if (widget.surah != nIndex) {
                            return const Center(child: Text('.........'));
                          } else {
                            return Card(
                              color: const Color(0xffaaaa55),
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                        topLeft: Radius.circular(150))),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          Icon(
                                            Icons.play_circle_fill,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            size: 35.sp,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            '(${listData[index]['Ayat'].toString()})',
                                            style: myStyle(size: 18.sp),
                                          ),
                                          Icon(
                                            Icons.more_vert,
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            size: 35.sp,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                        child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        listData[index]['Arabic'].toString(),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        maxLines: 2,
                                        style: GoogleFonts.adventPro(
                                            fontSize: 22.sp),
                                      ),
                                    )),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 5.h,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                        child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        listData[index]['Translation']
                                            .toString(),
                                        maxLines: 4,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.sp),
                                      ),
                                    )),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 5.h,
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Divider(
                                        color: Colors.brown,
                                        thickness: 1.sp,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                        });
                  }),
            ),
```

[image]

[image]

Output Screen:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems your problem is with the if and not the else but nonetheless...

One way to solve this would be to simply filter with where() your listData prior to rendering with the condition being used in the function. Then you use the filtered list.

Like so

````
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final filteredList = listData.where((e) => e['Surah'] == widget.surah);

    // Or the filtering could be in initState() to only be triggered 
    // once, up to you and how you manage state.

    return SizedBox(
              height: 490.h,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: loadData(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: filteredList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {                          
                            return Card(
                              color: const Color(0xffaaaa55),
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                        topLeft: Radius.circular(150))),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          Icon(
                                            Icons.play_circle_fill,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            size: 35.sp,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            '(${filteredList[index]['Ayat'].toString()})',
                                            style: myStyle(size: 18.sp),
                                          ),
                                          Icon(
                                            Icons.more_vert,
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            size: 35.sp,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                        child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        filteredList[index]['Arabic'].toString(),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        maxLines: 2,
                                        style: GoogleFonts.adventPro(
                                            fontSize: 22.sp),
                                      ),
                                    )),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 5.h,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                        child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        filteredList[index]['Translation']
                                            .toString(),
                                        maxLines: 4,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.sp),
                                      ),
                                    )),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 5.h,
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Divider(
                                        color: Colors.brown,
                                        thickness: 1.sp,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          
                        });
                  }),
            ),
  }```
````

Comment: Well definitely I missed it, but I want if (widget.surah != nIndex) should not display.

Comment: Alright, I am gonna post you my solution. I was in a rush prior.